# how to position div inside td according to time to looks like google calendar

Tags: php, jquery, css, css-position

HTML

```
<td time='10:00 AM'>
<span timeStart="00" timeEnd="10" class="entry deletable">Entery 1 from 10:00-10:15</span>
<span timeStart="15" timeEnd="30" class="entry deletable">Entery 2</span>
</td>
```

This is an example of how td looks inside my jquery/php calendar.

my question is

1. how can i make Css position and set height of those spans according to time start and time end, also how to avoid overlaping ?
2. should i or should i not include timeStart and end in html ? i can set style dynamicly on php that would be a cleaner way to do it !

---

i think i didnt make myself clear.

here is wt i have tried so far

html

```
<td style='width:60px;'>
<div style="position:relative">
<span style="position:absolute;top:00px;" title="Time:10:00 AM">demo patient</span>
<span style="position:absolute;top:40px;" title="Time:10:20 AM">new patient</span>
</div>
</td>
```

PHP used to generate this

```
echo"<span style='position:absolute;top:".
date("i", strtotime($data['time_booked']))."px;' title='{$data['time_booked']}'>{$data['name']}</span>";
```

Now i can position spans as i want, only problem is that if 2 bookings made same time they overlap , how can i avoid this ?

Comment: convert the times into a single unit, e.g. minutes, then use those minutes for height calculations, e.g. 10am-10:30am = 600 minutes - 630 minutes (past midnight), height = 30 minutes -> 2px/minute = 60px.

Comment: Also spans are inline, need to set to inline-block or block to assign a height.

Comment: You are talking about `divs` but using `spans` ...

Comment: Oh - and use data-attributes if you want to attach custom attributes to an element: <span data-timestart="00"></span>

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. It utilizes data-attributes to determine how big of a block to use. I also changed your spans to divs, if you need them inline-block you can change the css accordingly. [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rUu3p/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td time='10:00 AM'>
      <div data-time-start="00" data-time-end="15" class="entry deletable">Entry 1 from 10:00-10:15</div>
      <div data-time-start="15" data-time-end="45" class="entry deletable">Entry 2 from 10:15-10:45</div>
      <div data-time-start="45" data-time-end="60" class="entry deletable">Entry 3 from 10:45-11:00</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.entry{
  border-top:1px solid #000;
  background:#bad;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.entry').each(function (i) {
  var $this = $(this);
  timestart = $this.data('time-start'),
  timeend = $this.data('time-end');

  $this.height(timeend - timestart);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just go to Google's calendar. Download the html + stylesheets, and use you favorite code editor to study how they do it?